# Laravel multiple relationships; retrieve only one relationship (last eager)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query; all relationship links are made correctly as results are displayed so.

```
MUsers::select('id')
    ->where('id', session('saas.user.id'))
    ->with([
        'getClasses' => function($getClasses) {
            $getClasses->with([
                'getDocuments' => function($getDocuments) {
                    $getDocuments->select('id', 'cathegory_id');
                }
            ]);
        }
    ])->firstOrFail();
```

- `getClassesTeacher` is a `belongsToMany` relationship;
- `getDocuments` is a `belongsToMany` relationship;

How to retrieve only the last eager relationship without the need for further 'spaghetti line' processing. I've tried using `pluck` several times but it didn't work.

```
MUsers::select('id')
    ->where('id', session('saas.user.id'))
    ->with([
        'getClassesTeacher' => function($getClasses) {
            $getClasses->with([
                'getDocuments' => function($getDocuments) {
                    $getDocuments->select('id', 'cathegory_id' );
                }
            ]);
            $getClasses->get()->pluck('getDocuments'); // has no effect or returns "column 'getDocuments' not found"
        }
    ])->get()
    ->pluck('getClassesTeacher');  // does not return what I needed
```

Comment: Isn't `pluck()` used in the place of the likes of `get()`? Like: `$titles = DB::table('roles')->pluck('title');` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
get()
```

use

```
latest()->first()
```

Hope this will clear your issue